# Как в редакторе unity3d поменять skybox при помощи скрипта

Tags: unity3d

Никак не получается найти способ поменять Skybox Material программно внутри редактора.

Я уже знаю как поменять материал когда игра запущена, но он меняется на стандартный когда я её останавливаю. А мне нужно чтобы в он остался в окне сцены.

```
RenderSettings.skybox = new Material();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть есть какие-то способы сделать это и в редакторе тоже?